# How to fix the position of avalondock tabs in a wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I am using Avalondock in my WPF project to create multiple tabs containing layout documents. Is there a way to fix the position of the tabs so that the user can not  drag and interchange the position of the tabs.

Following is my code:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dockManager" AllowMixedOrientation="True" ActiveContentChanged="dockManager_ActiveContentChanged" Loaded="dockManager_Loaded" Mouse.MouseDown="dockManager_MouseDown">
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
            <avalonDock:AeroTheme/>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
        <avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title , NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TargetUpdated="TextBlock_TargetUpdated" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" />
                </StackPanel>


            </DataTemplate>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>

    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot x:Name="layout">
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockWidth="450" DockMinWidth="200" >
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane DockWidth="100*" x:Name="documentPane" >
                            <avalonDock:LayoutDocument CanClose="False" CanFloat="False"  ContentId="doc1" FloatingWidth="100">
                                <StackPanel>
                                <Frame BorderThickness="2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"   x:Name="Mainframe" Source="{Binding DisplayPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                                </StackPanel>
                            </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>


                </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>

            </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>

    </avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

set `CanRepositionItems="False"` in LayoutDocumentPane

```
 <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane DockWidth="100*" x:Name="documentPane" CanRepositionItems="False">
                        <avalonDock:LayoutDocument CanClose="False" CanFloat="False"  ContentId="doc1" FloatingWidth="100">
                            <StackPanel>
                            <Frame BorderThickness="2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"   x:Name="Mainframe" Source="{Binding DisplayPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ***CanFloat=false*** in LayoutDocument.

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dockManager" AllowMixedOrientation="True" ActiveContentChanged="dockManager_ActiveContentChanged" Loaded="dockManager_Loaded" Mouse.MouseDown="dockManager_MouseDown">
<avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
        <avalonDock:AeroTheme/>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title , NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TargetUpdated="TextBlock_TargetUpdated" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
  <avalonDock:LayoutRoot x:Name="layout">
    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockWidth="450" DockMinWidth="200" CanFloat="False">
        <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane DockWidth="100*" x:Name="documentPane"  >
            <avalonDock:LayoutDocument CanClose="False" CanFloat="False"  ContentId="doc1" FloatingWidth="100">
               <StackPanel>
                  <Frame BorderThickness="2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"   x:Name="Mainframe" Source="{Binding DisplayPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
        </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>
            </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
     </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the above solution but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

> AllowMixedOrientation="False" in avalonDock:DockingManager

this disable the user to drag and drop the tab side by side.

> CanRepositionItems="False" in avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane

this disable the user to move the tab order.

> CanFloat="False" in avalonDock:LayoutDocument

this disable the docking view to float.
Same goes to AnchorableView.

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager  Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dockManager" AllowMixedOrientation="False" ActiveContentChanged="dockManager_ActiveContentChanged" Loaded="dockManager_Loaded" Mouse.MouseDown="dockManager_MouseDown">
<avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
        <avalonDock:AeroTheme/>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.Theme>
    <avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title , NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" TargetUpdated="TextBlock_TargetUpdated" PreviewMouseDown="TextBlock_PreviewMouseDown"/>
                <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" />
            </StackPanel>


        </DataTemplate>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>

<avalonDock:LayoutRoot x:Name="layout">
    <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockWidth="450" DockMinWidth="200" >
        <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane DockWidth="100*" x:Name="documentPane" CanRepositionItems="False">
                        <avalonDock:LayoutDocument CanClose="False" CanFloat="False"  ContentId="doc1" FloatingWidth="100">
                            <StackPanel>
                            <Frame BorderThickness="2" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"   x:Name="Mainframe" Source="{Binding DisplayPage, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                            </StackPanel>
                        </avalonDock:LayoutDocument>
                    </avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane>


            </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>

        </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>

</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```